# What is difference between value and data-value in input type (HTML)

Tags: html

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="myname" data-value="dhoni" value="sachin">
</form>
```

What is difference between value and data-value in input type (HTML)

Comment: `value` = the value of the input, `data-value` = more of like a variable of sorts, which can be accessed by `$(element).data('value')` *(in jQuery)*. The `value` in `data-value` can be changed with other name, like `data-sonu`.

Answer (score 2):

They are both attributes, but the value attribute (together with name attribute) can be natively accessed by most server-side languages. Whereas data-value can only be natively accessed by the client-side.

Data attribute can also have different suffix, you could name it; data-name, data-email, data-content, and etc. You could say that the latter is customizable.

Run snippet below and see how I called data and value attributes;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $("input");

  // $("input").data("name");
  // $("input").val();

  alert("Data-value is " + input.data("value") + ". Data-element is " + input.data("element") + ". Value is " + input.val() + ".");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="myname" data-value="dhoni" data-element="input" value="sachin">
</form>
```